# How to internationalize my eclipse Rcp application?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, rcp

I tried to follow vogella (http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseInternationalization/article.html tutorial but I am facing some issue. After externalize the project when ever I tried to click PDT-->internationalize it is creating some properties file which is not different than my main properties file and all in default language i.e en .

2-I created a fragment project. for which the host plugin is my main project. I have a doubt that what should be the content of that fragment project.

Any help on this is really appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties files are just copied from the default locale to show you the properties that need to be translated. It is your responsibility to actually do the translation to the appropriate languages in these files.